# Property of the gamma function, and evaluation of a product

Tags: gamma-function

Using $\Gamma(n)= (n-1)\Gamma(n-1)$ , I get, $\Gamma(n + \frac{3}{2}) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}(2n+1)(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)..}{2^{n+1}} $, where there are $N = n+1$ brackets. This can be written as

$$\Gamma(n+\frac{3}{2}) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{n+1}}\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}[2(n-k)+3]$$

Is this reasoning correct, and how do I evaluate this product?

Comment: whoops that should be $2^{n+1}$ in the denominator

Answer (score 0):

Use
$$1\times3\times5\times\cdots\times(2n+1)
=\frac{(2n+1)!}{2\times 4\times\cdots\times(2n)}
=\frac{(2n+1)!}{2^n n!}$$
etc.

Comment: surely that is the answer to $$\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)$$, how is that related to my product?

Comment: and of course I have n+1 terms in that formula

Comment: @Think It's the product you asked to evaluate.

Comment: I mean, I know the products are calculating the same thing i.e. the product of odd numbers its just that its in a different form that is bugging me

Comment: and the limits are different

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to manipulate what I had written to get it in the form $$\prod_{k=1}^{y}(2k+1)$$ where y is related to n